# Ошибка Yandex Maps [[ M._makeCoordinates ]]

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Есть карта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если её просто пошевелить мышкой вываливается ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам код

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: О таких вещах нужно писать в техподдержку Яндекса.

Comment: Такая же проблема возникла пару дней назад, нашли ли вы решение?

Comment: Написал в тех. поддержку Яндекса. Пока решения нет, в некоторых браузерах этой ошибки нет. В Google Chrome и Opera ошибка есть, видимо из-за последних обновлений.

Comment: Мне пишут, что проблема должна быть исправлена. Исправилась проблема?

Comment: Да, без ошибок!

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была на стороне Yandex Maps.
Ошибку убрали.